# Escaping dollar sign in sed expression (for env var)

Tags: regex, sed, escaping

I have this text file: `There exists $COUNT things`

In my environment, I have $COUNT set to some number (say 5).

When I ran the following command

```
$export COUNT=5
$sed -e 's/\\$COUNT/$COUNT/' foo.txt
```

I expected `There exists 5 things` but got `There exists $COUNT things`

What is wrong with my sed regex?

Comment: see [Substitution Using Shell Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/1096/substitution/3519/substitution-using-shell-variables#t=201702090235204554934)

Answer (score 3):

Single quotes don't expand $ variables so change your sed expression to double quotes and use only one \